# How to get document snapshot in flutter[firebase]?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using GeoFlutterFire, a package to query locations of nearby users.

Here is my code.

```dart
Future<Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>>> getUsers() async { 
    GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: lat, longitude: long);
    var collectionref =  Firestore.instance.collection("locations");
    double radius = 50;
    String field = 'position';
    
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionref).within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field);
    stream.forEach((element) {print(element);});
}
```

I'm getting this printed in my console

```
[Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot']
```

I tried doing everything, nothing works out.
I also tried returning the `Stream` from the function, but it didn't work out.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getUsers() async* {
    GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: lat, longitude: long);
    var collectionref = Firestore.instance.collection("locations");
    double radius = 50;
    String field = 'position';
    yield* geo
        .collection(collectionRef: collectionref)
        .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field);
  }
```

Using `async*` you can return a `Stream`, and then you can use `yield*` to return the values, if you want to use this function in the `build()` method then you can use a `StreamBuilder` widget.

Comment: Hey! Bro I'm getting this printed in my console " Instance of '_ControllerStream<List<DocumentSnapshot>>'  " Could you please just tell me, how can i get the stream printed in the console?

Comment: how are u calling it?

Comment: Umm..bro I'm really new at dart. All i want is to call a function to print nearby users in my console when i press a button in my app. I tried the way given in this documentation to QUERY the users, the documentation is here https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire   i tried implementing that in a function, but i got that error "Instance of DocumentSnapshot. Please help.

Comment: Hey.. check this out..i tried this code, but it didn't work out. :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63099231/stream-listenlistdocumentsnapshot-documentlist-returns-instance-of-document