# stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) returns Instance of DocumentSnapshot.Flutter [Firebase]

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I just started learning Flutter and Dart.

When I tried to query the locations of nearby documents as stated in this documentation.[To QUERY] https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire , I got this printed in my console "Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot' "

Here is my code.

```
Future<void> GetusersLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    lat = position.latitude;
    long = position.longitude;
  }

Future<dynamic> getnearbyusers()async{

    await GetusersLocation();

    GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: lat, longitude: long);

    var collectionReference = _firestore.collection('locations');

    double radius = 50;
    String field = 'position';

 stream = geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
        .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field);
  }
```

In my Scaffold, I have:

```
FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () async  {
    await getnearbyusers().whenComplete(() => stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
         
         print(documentList[0]);

       }));
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first convert your DocumentSnapshot to a Dart Model class like

For example:

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final String username;
  final String email;

  User.fromDocumet(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    return User(
        id: documentSnapshot['id'],
        username: documentSnapshot['username'],
        email: documentSnapshot['email']);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'id: $id, name: $username, email: $email';
  }
}
```

Then you can use the toString() method from the User model class to print your value.

The above User class is just an example. Please create your own class based on how your Document is structured.